# Mixing problem-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My problem is the following:

A tank containing chocolate milk initially contains a mixture of 900 liters of milk and 100 liters of chocolate syrup. Milk is added to the tank at the rate of 16 liters per minute, and chocolate syrup is added to the tank at the rate of 4 liters per minute. At the same time, chocolate milk is withdrawn at the rate of 20 liters per minute. Assuming perfect mixing of milk and syrup, how much syrup (in liters) will be in the tank after one hour? You may round your answer to one decimal place. Do not include the units in your answer.

I assume that I should write some kind of differential equation to solve this problem above, but I still have no idea, how to do this. I appreciate every help.

Comment: Related question, that might be of interest, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946071/ode-for-mixing-problem/2329593#2329593

Answer (score 1):

Let $x(t)$ be the amount of milk in the tank after $t$ minutes. Now, let's see what we're told about its derivative:

We have a steady in-flow of $16$ litres of milk per minute. That means that $x'(t)$ gets a $+16$ term.

The out-flow is $20$ litres of mixture per minute, and the amount of milk in $20$ litres of mixture is $20\cdot \frac{x(t)}{900} = \frac{x(t)}{45}$. So $x'(t)$ gets a term of $-\frac{x(t)}{45}$.

These are all the things that affect the amount of milk in the tank, so we have
$$
x'(t) = 16 - \frac{x(t)}{45}
$$
(Some textbook examples have you working with the *concentration* of milk instead of the *amount*. While mathematically equivalent, I find it less obvious how to set up the equation in a case like that, not to mention the complications in case the total in-flow and out-flow of fluid aren't equal.)

As for the syrup, we have $20$ litres of fluid in, and $20$ litres of fluid out each minute, so the tank is at a steady $900$ litres. That means that the amount of syrup at time $t$ is $900 - x(t)$.